# Cannot find weblogic_home when setting up server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to get my java ee development environment setup but am running into issues when trying to add a new server in eclipse.

I have the oracle java ee version of eclipse, I also downloaded weblogic 12.1.2 and got it setup and running without issues (I can access the console fine). I got the development version of weblogic and unzipped it to "C:\wls12120". When I try to add a weblogic server in eclipse I try setting it to "C:\wls12120" but it gives me the following message: The path "C:\wls12120" does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install.

I have also tried various other paths within the folder but without success, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think the actual server resides at /wlsXXX/server/bin
i don't remember the exact path coz i haven't used/installed weblogic for a long time.

Comment: thanks maxx777, but I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted please explain what I can do to improve this question?

Comment: Here's your server=> `<WL_HOME>\server\lib\weblogic.jar`

Comment: well, i was trying to install weblogic to my system and i was unable to do so. better go for apache tomcat

Comment: Not an option as this is an existing project.

Comment: on my system i have successfully integrated weblogic 12c to netbeans (i prefer netbeans over eclipse". My server path was `c:\wls12120\wlserver`. hope that would work on eclipse too.

Comment: Have you checked answers like this? https://community.oracle.com/message/9726039

Answer (score 5):

First try, if you have proper installation and that your WS is instaled and configured properly. If not, check installation documentation. Very important is to have set the environmental variables JAVA_HOME and MV_HOME. For example in my case on Linux i have in `.profile`

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 export
>
> MW_HOME=/opt/weblogic/wls12130

Than start intitial scripts.

> . .$MW_HOME/configure.sh
>
> . $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh

Than start:

> $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/mydomain/startWebLogic.sh

The last lines looks like:

```
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[4]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:9002 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure" is now listening on 127.0.1.1:9002 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 127.0.1.1:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:204:76ff:fe22:a0d:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:204:76ff:fe22:a0d:9002 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9002 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 192.168.0.2:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[1]" is now listening on 192.168.0.2:9002 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started the WebLogic Server Administration Server "myserver" for domain "mydomain" running in development mode.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.> 
<Sep 29, 2015 1:25:25 PM CEST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
```

If WebLogic is started, than do `^C` to stop it and begin to integrate to Eclipse. First you must have installed Oracle OEPE plug-in. Than right click in Servers tab and choose new->Server Oracle-> Proper version of WS (in my case 12.1.3). In server host name fill proper IP address (in my case I used 192.168.1.0.2. not localhost) and proper port (default is 7001, but if it has conflict, change it using WebLogic Console before integration to the Eclipse. [ERROR: Oracle Weblogic Server port is already in use](http://kb.bizagi.com/Knowledgebase/ERROR-Oracle-Weblogic-Server-port-is-already-in-use) Mostly, even if it is there conflict, console works, if not, do it manually to edit `config.xml` in your `domain/config` directory. Proper way to the WS is $MW_HOME/wlserver (i.e. /opt/weblogic/wls12130/wlserver).

Answer (score 2):

The server is WL_HOME\server\lib\weblogic.jar

Based on that workout what the WL_HOME is; and that is the solution to the issue raised. Just note that this matter is INDEPENDENT of the domains - i.e where specific projects are located.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.to resolve this issue you **don't have to reinstall** your weblogic server.Do the **following steps to resolve the issue.**

1. Open the server view in your Eclipse and create a new server.
2. From the server type select the correct version of weblogic.
3. Click on Configure run time environment.Another popup will open.
4. Select your weblogic server and click on Edit button.
5. click on browse button available at the last weblogic home Textbox
6. **Point out your weblogic home like
   < Your Drive >:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_< Version >**

Answer (score 1):

At least in my installation I was able to run like this:

[image]

Comment: wlserver folder is the one where you have created 'AdminServer' to deploy your .ear/.war file locally, so this is the one folder (WebLogic) which should be given as 'WebLogic home'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your unzipped server not contains this file: C:\wls12120\registry.xml

http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-intellij-idea-12

Answer (score 0):

If if is a fresh installation, you will need to open a shell, set JAVA_HOME, and run the config.bat/config.sh. It should start up an listen on port 7001. You can connect to the instance that starts up via the admin console link. For Eclipse you will need to point to the instance you created (e.g. x:\wls12130\wlserver)

Answer (score 0):

please run **configure.cmd** file for first time configuration.
Then follow add server configuration steps as per you steps.

Comment: This steps are only for First Time if u have got error as you have mentation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows/Preferences/Servers and use the Search button and set the folder where you know that there is a server. It will find out the configuration settings. It worked for me.